# Get a path taken by a particle

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

Is it possible to convert a baked particle system to a curve (or set of curves) representing the path taken by each of the particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[Btrace](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Btrace)** addon.

[image]

It allows you to trace particles and to also convert the paths to curves.

Comment: I'm using 2.76 and the only "Add Curve" add-ons I have available are Extra Objects, IvyGen, Sapling, and Simplify Curves..

Comment: @ajwood Corrected. This is bummer, it was bundled I believe. And awesome addon. I hope it still works.

Comment: I downloaded it and seems to work so far!